# How can I do a regex replace using a List as the possible match entires?

Tags: regex, dart

I have a list of terms which I want to match as follows:

```
final List _emotions = [
  '~~wink~~',
  '~~bigsmile~~',
  '~~sigh~~',
];
```

And a second list of replacements:

```
final List _replacements = [
  '0.gif',
  '1.gif',
  '2.gif',
];
```

SO that if I have text:

```
var text = "I went to the store and got a ~~bigsmile~~";
```

I could have it replace the text as

```
I went to the store and got a <img src="1.gif" />
```

So essentially, I was thinking of running a regex replace on my `text` variable,  but the search pattern would be based on my `_emotions` List.

Forming the replacement text should be easy, but I'm not sure how I could use the list as the basis for the search terms

How is this possible in dart?

Comment: Does Dart allow you to use a function as the replacement in a regexp replace, like most other languages do?

Comment: @Barmar Yes I believe so

Comment: Then that's the solution. Make a regular expression with all the elements of `_emotions` as alternatives, e.g. `~~wink~~|bigsmile~~|~~sigh~~`. In the replacement function, find the index of the matched string, and return the corresponding element of `_replacements`.

Comment: It's even easier if you combine the two arrays into a `Map`.

Comment: @Barmar Ok so programmatically connect all the list items into a giant string `~~wink~~|~~bigsmile~~, etc` and use that as my regex pattern.  Ok that makes sense, but does regex give you an index of which one actually matched?

Comment: No. You get the matched string, which will be identical to one of the patterns. You search for it in the array to get the index.

Comment: But if you use a `Map` instead of 2 arrays, you don't need to do that. Just use the matched string as the key, and return the value.

Comment: @Barmar Ok I think I follow, this is what I came up with: `var regex = RegExp("(?${_emotions.join('|')})", caseSensitive: false);` which is of course giving me an `Invalid group error`, I think maybe because my match group has a `~` in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to merge the two string lists into a single `Map<String, String>` that will serve as a dictionary (make sure the `_emotions` strings are in lower case since you want a case insensitive matching), and then join the `_emotions` strings into a single alternation based pattern.

After getting a match, use `String#replaceAllMapped` to find the right replacement for the found emotion.

Note you can shorten the pattern if you factor in the `~~` delimiters (see code snippet below). You might also apply more advanced techniques for the vocabulary, like regex tries (see [my YT video on this topic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YlN-ZBa5DvU)).

```dart
final List<String> _emotions = [
    'wink',
    'bigsmile',
    'sigh',
];
final List<String> _replacements = [
    '0.gif',
    '1.gif',
    '2.gif',
];
Map<String, String> map = Map.fromIterables(_emotions, _replacements);
String text = "I went to the store and got a ~~bigsmile~~";
RegExp regex = RegExp("~~(${_emotions.join('|')})~~", caseSensitive: false);
print(text.replaceAllMapped(regex, (m) => '<img src="${map[m[1]?.toLowerCase()]}" />'));
```

Output:

```
I went to the store and got a <img src="1.gif" />
```